# Uploading files with drag and drop is unstable

Tags: javascript, upload, base64

I am creating a drag and drop uploader and I am using base64 to send the data to my server using a hidden field. (The file will be sent later, not as soon as its dropped).

Testing small image files and text files works really well, but when I try a 20MB zip or a 2MB WAV the whole this becomes unstable. Google Chrome crashes or displays a blank output box and firefox hangs for ages and eventually displays the base64 string. IE actually works for once and displays the string the fastest but still with an unacceptable wait time.

Is my code inefficient or is it something else?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<input name="filebox" type="text" id="filebox" size="300">
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();

var filelist = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
file = filelist[0];
var reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = function(e) {
document.getElementById('filebox').value = e.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file) //readAsdataURL
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}


var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

This test page is live at: http://www.tabbicat.info/local/propellor/drop.html

Comment: How are you performing the base64 encoding? Are you using native window.btoa or some javascript crafted function?

Comment: FileReader() outputs to it with this line: reader.readAsDataURL(file). I don't quite fully understand how this works though because the reader.onload function is what sets the input box?

Comment: What happens when you drop one of these big files onto the demo at html5rocks, where this code came from? I dropped a 23Mb one there and it came up in seconds with info. Tried the same at you link, and the same, within seconds.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using FileReader here?  I so no reason, based on the code you are using.  FileReader reads the contents of the file, which can take a while depending on the size of the file.  Why do you need to do this?  Just send the File object to your server.

Comment: I have been looking around for a simple way to "drag and drop" upload and that seemed like the best way, can't seem to find many resources on this sort of thing. The file shouldn't be uploaded immediately but only when the other form fields are complete and the user clicks Submit. The hidden input idea was a simple way to store the information.

Comment: Like I said, just send the File objects contained in the `files` property of the `DataTransfer` object to your server via XHR2.

Comment: @RayNicholus Ok, thank you I will look into that. Sounds much more civilised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried your live link and the same demo that is available at [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), and both took around 2 seconds for a 23Mb file. I then tried to create that exact code at jsfiddle but for some reason the drag and drop did not want to function. So I used the file selector method instead. Again, it took just about 2 seconds to read in the file. All I can think is that you may possibly have some machine memory problems, like a lack of it or something, or maybe HDD transfer speeds? Or perhaps there is some issue in browser drag an drop code. :/

Anyway, you can see the file selector method at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/aeZJe/)

```
#progress_bar {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    clear: both;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
#progress_bar.loading {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#progress_bar .percent {
    background-color: #99ccff;
    height: auto;
    width: 0;
}

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />
<button onclick="abortRead();">Cancel read</button>
<div id="progress_bar">
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
</div>

var reader;
var progress = document.querySelector('.percent');

function abortRead() {
    reader.abort();
}

function errorHandler(evt) {
    switch (evt.target.error.code) {
        case evt.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
            alert('File Not Found!');
            break;
        case evt.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
            alert('File is not readable');
            break;
        case evt.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
            break; // noop
        default:
            alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
    };
}

function updateProgress(evt) {
    // evt is an ProgressEvent.
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
        // Increase the progress bar length.
        if (percentLoaded < 100) {
            progress.style.width = percentLoaded + '%';
            progress.textContent = percentLoaded + '%';
        }
    }
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    // Reset progress indicator on new file selection.
    progress.style.width = '0%';
    progress.textContent = '0%';

    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
    reader.onprogress = updateProgress;
    reader.onabort = function (e) {
        alert('File read cancelled');
    };
    reader.onloadstart = function (e) {
        document.getElementById('progress_bar').className = 'loading';
    };
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        // Ensure that the progress bar displays 100% at the end.
        progress.style.width = '100%';
        progress.textContent = '100%';
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('progress_bar').className='';", 2000);
    }

    // Read in the image file as a binary string.
    reader.readAsDataURL(evt.target.files[0]);
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: I tried the same file I have been using on my testing server and it took about two seconds also on jsfiddle. I notice that that code isn't grabbing the base64 string from the file though. Perhaps this is where the problem lies?

Comment: I changed it to ´readAsDataURL´ and updated jsfiddle, but the speed was not noticeably different.

Comment: Would the down voters care to leave a comment as to why, and give me a chance to fix whatever was unhelpful about this post?